# Cell Colors Using OpenPyxl 2.02

Tags: colors, styles, cell, openpyxl

I've just upgraded from openpyxl 1.6.2 to 2.02, and have a question regarding setting cell colors.

The **Styles** function should handle all the necessary formatting, and that includes using the **Fill** function to set the cell color. This latter function has *fill_type* as one of its arguments. How do you set this to a solid fill? In previous versions, this was done using something like:

```
mycell.style.fill.fill_type = Fill.FILL_SOLID
```

The [documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/styles.html), which looks like it's in progress, seems to suggest that setting fill_type = Fill.FILL_SOLID will do the trick (scroll down to the notes at the bottom of the page). But I'm getting an AttributeError when trying it.

```
from openpyxl.styles import Fill, Color
from openpyxl.styles.colors import RED

redfill = Fill(fill_type=Fill.FILL_SOLID,start_color=RED)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    redfill = Fill(fill_type=Fill.FILL_SOLID,start_color=RED)
AttributeError: type object 'Fill' has no attribute 'FILL_SOLID'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constants are now module and not class constants.

```
   from openpyxl.styles import fills, PatternFill
   fill = PatternFill(patternType=fills.FILL_SOLID)
```

Though I think it's easier just to use `patternType='solid'`

Answer (score 8):

A style is immutable once created, you have to construct a new one and assign it to the cell `style` property like this:

```
mycell.style = Style(fill=PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor=Color('FFFF0000')))
```

this will turn the cell red.